# How to integrate DevOps CI-CD for Azure Databricks (build notebooks,create pipeline)

Tags: azure-databricks

I am new to Azure Databricks to implement ETL and needs to understand how to integrate CI-CD for databricks.I tried with several sites for reference to understand the process.I created a project and is stuck with pipeline->build for databricks notebook and test plan.Can someone help me out?
I have a dev databricks workspace already provisioned and associated devops project with master and dev branches in devops.
How to set up the build or build server and deploy to other environment workspace

I had referred to below urls prior to posting the question
https://thedataguy.blog/ci-cd-with-databricks-and-azure-devops/
https://github.com/annedroid/DevOpsforDatabricks
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DataThirstLtd.databricksDeployScriptsTasks